# How to create a github repository directly from git bash?

Tags: linux, git, bash, github, git-branch

Frequently what I do is

1) Create a repository on **github**

2) In my **gitbash**, I do `git remote add origin <url>`

3) Do my stuff to it, finally push

What I want to know is that, can I create a **repository on github** directly from **git bash**? I don't want to first go on github, create it, and then go back to gitbash, remote it, and then mess with it. I want a way to do this directly from gitbash.

`git create this repo on github`

Something of that sort, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub's API is not covered by the core `git` implementation. So9 what you are asking for directly, is not possible. If a software recommendation is also OK as an answer, I would recommend to look at `hub` from GitHub: https://github.com/github/hub

After some configuration (setting up OATH tokens with GitHub), you can `hub init`, and your repo wil be created on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, there are tools like [hub](https://github.com/github/hub/) and [git-spindle](https://github.com/seveas/git-spindle) that enrich the Git command with more power regarding Git hosters. Maybe there are more, but those are the two I know.

I used both and strongly recommend `git-spindle`. It has better naming conventions (upstream is `upstream`, your fork is `origin`, in `hub` upstream is `origin` and your fork is `<your username>`), a better installation (For using `hub` with calling `git` you have to set up an alias that replaces `git` by `hub`, `git-spindle` installs as several Git sub-commands, one for GitHub, one for BitBucket, one for GitLab [`hub` only supports GitHub]), better separation (with `git-spindle` you call `git hub ...`, `hub` adds additional parameters to existing commands).